# Is there a way to trick CS:GO into thinking I have another teammate for co-op missions?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I don't have many Steam friends who play GO at the same time I'm available and as such most of my guardian co-op missions are incomplete. I'd love to finish them in time for the end of Wildfire and get my gold badge.

Is there a way to trick CS:GO into thinking I have another teammate for co-op missions? I can't play the missions without one other player and I don't know if there is a way to make Steam believe I am playing with someone else.

Comment: Please mark the comment below as it answers your question. There simply is no way of "tricking" the game into thinking you have a team-mate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it on your own and there is no way I know of tricking CS in to thinking you have a partner. Also, some of the missions require 2 players to get through the rounds, i.e. somewhere where you have to open gates with 2 switches that need to be activated at the same time.

If you solo queue or play casual games, just talk a bit and be friendly with your team. If you get a response from people you can request them as friends or straight up ask them if they want to do a co-op mission when the game is over.

Most of the people on my list are people that I've found friendly in matches I've played in. Also, with them playing in a match I played in, they are usually online at the same sort of time as me.

GLHF

Answer (score 2):

I tried achieving this too, but it was not possible. You wont be able to start the search until the second slot is filled.

Anyways it would not be called Coop Mission when it is not supposed to be a coop Mission. It would be pretty hard for you to achieve the mission alone and end into not having fun playing the game.

You have to search someone who plays the missions with you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to trick it. The best you can do is to play with console commands.

Start up a local server 9with bots) and type into the console "maps" to view the map list. then type "map *mapname*" to change the local server's map to the one you want.

You will probably need two more commands too, for changing the game mode, but I cant remember what they were off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the various "No" answers, it is possible to find people willing to play by posting in the Steam forums.  I haven't done it for this game specifically, but on various other games that is how I managed to get a coop partner.  Within an hour I get a response/friends request etc and then I can move on with the game.

Generally, you find people willing to help and/or in the same position as you.